# Economic valuation of green spaces using GIS

Tags: value, environmental-economics, public-goods

I was wondering if there are any standard methods that are employed to obtain insight of the economic value of tree cover in a particular area. I assumed using negative [difference vegetation index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index) coupled with economic value of ground cover as proxy but this is not supported by any literature in my search.

So if there any datasets (preferably free) that show the spatial value variations for green spaces, their suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: The [EVRI](https://www.evri.ca/en) database may be helpful (you have to register but it is free).

Comment: Have you looked on [heat island effect](https://www.dailytelegraph.com.au/newslocal/central-sydney/sydney-city-heat-map-shows-areas-where-temperatures-rise-due-to-urban-heat-island-effect/news-story/c49aece051b7c6a06862825d99c90fae) studies? They might have worked with economic valuations

Comment: @LimonadaPT I'll look at them right away